# How to create query with list of parameters in GraphQL?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, graphql

I trying to create Query where is it possible to pass multiple parameters, so in `models.graphqls` I added this:

```
type Query {
    productsByParameters(category: String, page: Int, size: Int, parameters: [QueryParameter]): [Product]
}
```

My resolver looks like:

```
fun productsByParameters(category: String, page: Int, size: Int, parameters: List<QueryParameter>)
```

Unfortunately, this approach doesn't work error is:

```
Caused by: com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.SchemaClassScannerError: Unable to match type definition (ListType{type=TypeName{name='QueryParameter'}}) with java type (class [Lcom.bd.model.QueryParameter;): Java class is not a List or generic type information was lost: class [Lcom.bd.model.QueryParameter;
```

Do you have any idea what is wrong here? Am I missing something?

Comment: Will it work if you provide `Array<QueryParameter>` type instead of `List<QueryParameter>` in kotlin?

Comment: I just check, If I switch to the `Array` nothing change, the error still occurs.